# SSH check to Github resolves to Gitlab

Tags: github, ssh, gitlab

***Challenge:***

I am currently setting up SSH access to my **Github** account and after following the instructions as highlighted here https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh, I tried testing the connection. Which led me to run the `ssh git@github.com` command as shown in the screenshot below. 
What I do not understand is why at all the connection is resolving to **Gitlab**?

```
itunuloluwa@MacBook-Pro .ssh % ssh -T git@github.com
Welcome to GitLab, @ifatoki!
```

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnfWo.png)

***Context:***

- This is a new Macbook pro and I migrated all my settings from a previous one that had SSH setup for both Github and Gitlab. Those keys hence exist in this mac now.
- Because of this, I removed the keys from my Gitlab account but when I still run the check, it resolves (which is rather weird)

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb, I couldn't respond immediately due to some maintenance being done on StackOverflow that prevented edits at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some digging and figured the challenge was with my config file `~/.ssh/config`.
It was of the form

```
HostName gitlab.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  ForwardAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab_id_rsa

Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Simply modifying it like below fixed the problem

```
Host gitlab
  HostName gitlab.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  ForwardAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab_id_rsa

Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```